# Zoomable RoundImageView - RoundImageView is still rectangle

Tags: java, android, imageview, scaling, foreground

I am trying to make zoomable RoundImageView. I am using this [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java)
but I extend it with [RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView/blob/master/roundedimageview/src/main/java/com/makeramen/roundedimageview/RoundedImageView.java) not with standard ImageView. This TouchImageView is in some FrameLayouts which have these these backround:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#FFF"/>
```

This background also have TouchImageView. When I call on it function setOval(true) everything seems fine, until I start zooming. It's look like it only create rounded bitmap, but ImageView is still rectangle...

PS: I need to have oval not circle.

There are some images:

Before zooming:

[image]

After zooming:

[image]

Thank you for every answer! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For thoose who have the same issue. I find [MaskableFrameLayout](https://github.com/christophesmet/android_maskable_layout) which is pretty easy to use. It extends FrameLayout so it's possible to have zoomable view in it. Just create oval or your shape in drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/></shape>
```

and use setMask(drawable). Also you need to setPorterDuffXferMode(...). I used DST_IN.

Hope it helps!